# define global variables and functions in build.gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

Is there a way to define global variables in `build.gradle` and make them accessible from everywhere.

I mean something like this

```
def variable = new Variable()

def method(Project proj) {
    def value = variable.value
}
```

Because that way it tells me that it `cannot find property`.
Also I'd like to do the same for the methods.
I mean something like this

```
def methodA() {}
def methodB() { methodA() }
```

Comment: By everywhere you mean everywhere in source code?

Comment: `ext` namespace is what you need

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use extra properties.

```
ext.propA = 'propAValue'
ext.propB = propA
println "$propA, $propB"

def PrintAllProps(){
  def propC = propA
  println "$propA, $propB, $propC"
}

task(runmethod) << { PrintAllProps() }
```

Running `runmethod` prints:

```
gradle runmethod
propAValue, propAValue
:runmethod
propAValue, propAValue, propAValue
```

Read more about [Gradle Extra Properties here.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)

You should be able to call functions from functions without doing anything special:

```
def PrintMoreProps(){
  print 'More Props: '
  PrintAllProps()
}
```

results in:

```
More Props: propAValue, propAValue, propAValue
```